# Google Earth Engine: how to display the entire layers' names?

Tags: google-earth-engine, layers, api, display

I imported many Landsat images through Google Earth Engine. The issue is that the windows to select the layers does not display their name entirely (see picture). How can I extend the window to see the complete names of my layers ?

This is how I name them:

```
for(var a = 1974; a < 2022; a++){
  Map.addLayer(finalCol.filterMetadata('year', 'equals', a), {}, ' '+a, false)
}
```

"a" is the year of the layer as a string.

[image: Bugged API]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The layer names shouldn't be truncated like that, and the title of it should not be in red-on-white text either. Something strange is going on that is not part of how the Code Editor is intended to function. I tried a script that names layers like your sample, and it displays readably as it should, for me.

[image]

I suggest disabling any browser extensions you may have installed that can modify the page, or trying a different browser or computer to see what might be affecting this. If you can identify the circumstances where this happens and it's not due to a misbehaving extension, please send the Earth Engine team a bug report by clicking the [image: exclamation point] button and choosing the "Send Code Editor feedback" option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! 

I somehow managed to get rid of the issue in a messy way. I noticed that if I add a single layer with a long name, it displays the names correctly. 

I appended the example code for adding a Landsat 8 image:  

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
                  .filterDate('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31')
                  .map(maskL8sr);

var visParams = {
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4,
};
Map.setCenter(114.0079, -26.0765, 9);
Map.addLayer(dataset.median(), visParams);